# What is this single-engine low-wing propeller plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I found this picture in [an article about constant speed propellers](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aircraft-systems/how-a-constant-speed-prop-works/), but there was no reference to the type of aircraft. The Flickr account that first posted the image doesn't exist anymore. I did some research myself, I thought it could be a Cessna or a Beechcraft, but I don't know much about it and none of the models I found was a perfect match.

[image: Small single-engine low wing airplane]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That’s a Piper PA-28R Arrow.  Most likely an PA-28R-201 Arrow III, by the looks of it.

Comment: It looks exactly like the Arrow III that I sometimes fly, except this one has cowl latches and a tail beacon.

Comment: Are there any specific features that are characteristic of that particular model?

Comment: Chiefly the Arrow III has the tapered wing as opposed to the Hershey bar wings of the older Arrow I/II aircraft.  The III also holds 72gal usable fuel as opposed to the 48gal useable of the Arrow I/II.